# Why are my C++ includes defining vars multiple times?

Tags: c++, c-preprocessor

I understand that pre-processor commands are an important part of header files to prevent vars and classes from being defined more than once.

I have been running into issues with my vars being defined multiple times - even with pre-processor wrappers. Here is a sample project that is experiencing compiler errors:

Header:

```
// TestInclude.h
#ifndef TESTINCLUDE_H_
#define TESTINCLUDE_H_

int myInt;

#endif /*TESTINCLUDE_H_*/
```

C++:

```
// TestInclude.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "IncludeMe.h"
#include "TestInclude.h"

int main( int argc, char* args[] )
{
    std::cin >> myInt;

    IncludeMe thisClass;

    std::cin >> myInt;
}
```

Header:

```
// IncludeMe.h
#ifndef INCLUDEME_H_
#define INCLUDEME_H_

class IncludeMe
{
private:
    int privateInt;
public:
    IncludeMe();
};

#endif /*INCLUDEME_H_*/
```

C++:

```
// IncludeMe.cpp
#include <iostream>
#include "IncludeMe.h"
#include "TestInclude.h"

IncludeMe::IncludeMe()
{
    std::cout << "myInt: " << myInt;
}
```

Then I compile like this:

Makefile:

```
all:
g++ -g -o TestInclude TestInclude.cpp IncludeMe.cpp
```

And I get the following error:

> /tmp/ccrcNqqO.o: In function `IncludeMe':
>       /home/quakkels/Projects/c++/TestInclude/IncludeMe.cpp:6: multiple definition of `myInt'
>       /tmp/ccgo6dVT.o:/home/quakkels/Projects/c++/TestInclude/TestInclude.cpp:7: first defined here
>       collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
>       make: *** [all] Error 1

Why am I getting this error when I'm using pre-processor conditionals in my header files?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Include guards do not protect against multiple *definitions*. They only protect against infinite recursive inclusion. (You can of course include the same header in multiple translation units!)

You should never have object definitions* in the header; only *declarations*:

**header.hpp:**

```
extern int a;
```

**file.cpp:**

```
#include "header.hpp"

int a = 12;
```

<sub>*) You *can* have class definitions in a header file, as well as `inline` functions and class member functions.</sub>

Comment: Formally, it tells the compiler that the following declaration is not a definition. In simpler terms, it tells the compiler that the definition of the declared variable is elsewhere, and the linker should resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

You should use `extern int myInt;` in header files and only write `int myInt;` in the single .cpp file where you want to define it.

Some projects use a preprocessor macro like "IN_FOO_CPP" to make that happen automatically with #ifdefs.